# Function runs after another function that comes after

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, promise, unhandled-exception

I'm currently trying to code a discord bot using node.js. Currently, I have a function that returns a value which a variable is set to. Afterwards, the console prints out the variable. However, the variable is printed out on the console before it gets assigned the value from the function.

The code:

```
 if(commands[0] === "getlevel"){
  let region = commands[1] + "1";
  let username = commands[2];
  var summonerLevel;

  console.log(region, username);

  API.setRegion(region);

  summonerLevel = await API.getSummonerLevel(username);

  console.log("HI");
  console.log(summonerLevel);

  message.channel.send(summonerLevel);
  }
});
```

So what happens is that the console prints about summonerLevel before the API.getSummonerLevel(username) function executes. How would I make it so that the getSummonerLevel() function runs before console.log()?

Code for function:

```
RiotAPI.prototype.getSummonerLevel = function(_username){

var summonerJSON; var summoner;
var url = baseURL1 + region + baseURL2 + "/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + _username + "?api_key=" + API_KEY;

console.log("Before");

var options = {
    uri: url,
    simple: false
};

request.get(options)
    .then(function(body){
        console.log("After");
        summonerJSON = body;
        summoner = JSON.parse(summonerJSON);
        console.log(summoner);
        console.log(summoner.summonerLevel);
        return summoner.summonerLevel;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        //should.throw.error.to.console();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
});
}
```

Also, another problem I have is I get an unhandled promise rejection warning and the .catch() that comes after request.get(...) doesn't seem to solve it. How would I fix that was well?

Console log (not sure if this is useful but...):

Before
HI
undefined
(node:13624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
(node:13624) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
After
{ id: 45932456,
  accountId: 206692908,
  name: 'fire263',
  profileIconId: 911,
  revisionDate: 1511729881000,
  summonerLevel: 36 }
36

Comment: You're looking to make use of a `promise`.

Comment: Read what the error log says.

Comment: `getSummonerLevel ` doesn't return anything

Comment: @JaromandaX It doesn't? So the return has to be outside of the request/then/catch functions then, right?

Comment: Not saying you need to move any existing return in those callback functions, I'm saying you need to *have* a return in `getSummonerLevel` ... I'd say, `return request.get(options)....` will help

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues on your code.

Code for function:

```
RiotAPI.prototype.getSummonerLevel = function(_username){

  var summonerJSON; var summoner;
  var url = baseURL1 + region + baseURL2 + "/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + _username + "?api_key=" + API_KEY;

  console.log("Before");

  var options = {
    uri: url,
    simple: false
  };

  return request.get(options) // you need to return the promise
    .then(function(body){
      console.log("After");
      summonerJSON = body;
      summoner = JSON.parse(summonerJSON);
      console.log(summoner);
      console.log(summoner.summonerLevel);
      return summoner.summonerLevel;
    })
    .catch(function(err){ // you should only use `.catch` once
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

As jaromanda x mentioned, you need to return the `request.get` call which in itself is a promise.

But also you shouldn't use multiple `.catch` calls because if you do it and you do not handle it correctly (read: continue the rejection chain) it won't go to the second `.catch` call that you had.

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

More specifically this part: "**The Promise returned by catch() is rejected if onRejected throws an error or returns a Promise which is itself rejected; otherwise, it is resolved.**"

Hopefully this will give you enough information to progress on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getSummonerLevel` does not return a promise, which is necessary to be awaitable. The easiest way you can achieve that is to make it `async` as well:

```
RiotAPI.prototype.getSummonerLevel = async function(_username) {
    var url = baseURL1 + region + baseURL2 + "/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + _username + "?api_key=" + API_KEY;

    console.log("Before");

    var options = {
        uri: url,
        simple: false
    };

    try {
        var body = await request.get(options);
        console.log("After");
        var summonerJSON = body;
        var summoner = JSON.parse(summonerJSON);
        console.log(summoner);
        console.log(summoner.summonerLevel);
        return summoner.summonerLevel;
    } catch (err) {
        //should.throw.error.to.console();
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```